# close/reopen wars on Mathoverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, specific-question, closed-questions, re-open

Sometimes one sees a situation like with this question:
[Cargo Cult Science in mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303325/cargo-cult-science-in-mathematics)

which goes on hold and back again a number of times.
Should there be a limit to the number of such rounds?
IMHO a majority should not override a substantial minority, which bothered with voting to re-open.

---

EDIT: I should have split this into two questions; apologies to all involved.

Comment: I agree, and made some suggestions for changes.  (See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2806/some-proposals-for-modifications-of-the-process-of-closing-reopening-questions .)  But there didn't seem to be any consensus on this.  For my part, I don't vote to close anything that has been closed once and reopened.

Comment: one can only vote to reopen the question once. It would be good to know, just in case, whether votes to close can also be cast only once.

Comment: Do I understand that you are advocating that a minority should implement as they please on this forum?  If not, please clarify.  While I don't enjoy the current system, I don't have a better suggestion.  It seems the forum community is divided on the matter of propriety of the question.  Gerhard "Perhaps Have A MathAlternate Forum?" Paseman, 2018.06.25.

Comment: I am against a dictatorship of the majority, or, if you like, first past the pole system. I think if there is enough interest in the question from sufficiently qualified group of users, the question should live.

Comment: The question should live, and the forum should die?  Gerhard "That Is A Concern Here" Paseman, 2018.06.25.

Comment: Why would a forum die? A forum would die (or at least suffer, under the current rules) if it had a sufficiently big group of hooligans who go and close questions at random...

Comment: This question was hardly closed randomly, and the closers are not hooligans.

Comment: I agree with this, I just think that the situation is far from ideal. E.g. the history of who voted for closing and who voted for re-opening is getting lost, instead of kept publuc.

Comment: It's not lost.  You just have to look at the edit history.

Comment: Another comment: it's up to 11 edits.  That's absurd.

Comment: Way one. One of the people named on the thread enlists assistance in getting the post removed. Another enlists more assistance to get the forum shut down.  MathOverflow LLC is unable to raise the funds to counter this assistance. Dead forum.  Gerhard "Imagine The Kind Of Assistance" Paseman, 2018.06.25.

Comment: Way two. Encouraged by this question, other questions appear, talking about whether this or that publication is " really about mathematics ", and leads to statements which are more political than mathematical in nature, divisive, and thus a new atmosphere which permeates the forum. Those who strive to repel this atmosphere give up, and leave the forum to go the way of sci.math.  Undead forum perhaps, but no longer living.  Gerhard "Perhaps Run By Some Zombies?" Paseman, 2018.06.25.

Comment: After eight years on this forum, this is perhaps my second vote cast to close.  I don't do these things lightly, nor without consideration.  Gerhard "Not Quite Hooligan Style, Either" Paseman, 2018.06.25.

Comment: I voted to close, but certainly not at random. Speaking of not so random behavior, the author of that question has a long history of using MO for soapboxing and advertising. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268163/was-cauchy-prescient) you have an example in which he asked a question he has answered himself in a paper. That post was pushed to the front page by 31 (sic!) edits. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226277/what-is-a-grossone) he ridicules Sergeyev, which is a significant part of the current post. At some point, I give up on the presumption of good faith.

Comment: I agree with @Michael. My feeling is that at this point the author of that question is mostly using MO and MSE as platform to promote their own papers. Even with the crankiest soapboxing cranks (e.g. WM) it is easy to mistake an isolated question as a reasonable question. But when a user exhibits a pattern, these questions needs to be seem in a broader context. And for this author, this does not look good.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, the post on Sergeyev that you linked has a reputation score of 40 and is thus one of the post popular ones on the site.  The post on Cauchy that you linked has a positive reputation of 5 and has led to a lively discussion.  Your allegations are odious and quarrelsome, as are some of the others appearing in this space.  The *comments* containing such accusations should be deleted.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Everyone can follow the links I gave and decide for themselves what to make of it. If you find something I said "odious", you can of course flag it. But popularity is certainly not a reason not to close a post. There are several closed questions with a score of more than 200.

Comment: "the post on Sergeyev that you linked has a reputation score of 40 and is thus one of the post popular ones on the site.", assuming the first "post" is a typo for "most", that is a highly subjective claim. The top 150 questions all have score >90 (and nearly all have at least 100). And if you want to argue that your questions received a lot of votes, let's also talk about the incredible number of downvotes they have procured over time.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, with all due respect to an MSE moderator, your comparison does not have any merit. Notice that the question on Sergeyev that you linked was never closed and reopened, and led to a thoughtful discussion. My purpose there was to bring the Sergeyev phenomenon to the attention of the mathematical public and elicit evaluations, which were indeed provided (some of them quite popular).

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, frankly I don't really understand your objection to my Cauchy post, either. This is obviously an active area of historical research, with publications in respected journals on both sides of the issue. There is similarly disagreement about this among mathematicians. I believe the discussion at that question was similarly fruitful and meaningful. Just because I happened to have published in the area doesn't seem sufficient reason to create a veto on MO posts :-)

Comment: @MikhailKatz I have no principled objections, but you should have made clear in  your post from the beginning that you have actually answered the question already and are just looking for further material. And 31 edits are a bit much...

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, perhaps this space is not the ideal location for such a discussion but since you have brought up the issue I would like to point out that in historical scholarship you don't prove theorems (or find mistakes in theorems).  Since history is not based on a system of axioms, the best one can do is present one's arguments as convincingly as possible and point out hidden flaws in approaches one disagrees with.  I personally find Detlef Laugwitz's approach to Cauchy the most convincing, but I don't presume to have the exclusive prerogative on the truth, and am always receptive to

Comment: ... other points of view, unlike some individuals (I am not referring to you) participating in this particular discussion. @MichaelGreinecker

Comment: P.S. A related thought: the amount of flak Laugwitz got from received historians for his take on Cauchy is simply unbelievable.  I saw things more strident than accusations of soapboxing. The general tenor is: "how can you stick to your position on Cauchy when we are all against it?" (and presumably would have downvoted it if given a chance :-) @MichaelGreinecker

Comment: Mathematicians (apart from complete nerds and/or loners) like to talk about questions related to their own work, online or otherwise. This might be different from your own experience, e.g. people who mathematically grew up in big friendly departments with lively common rooms won't quite get this point.

I don't see why talking about one's own work ought to be discouraged.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik 1. The desirability of a discussion of a topic does not imply the desirability of discussing the topic on MO, which is not made for discussions and IMHO benefits from the narrower focus as a Q & A. 2. Nobody discouraged talking about one's own work. Not mentioning one's own work was the issue mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, it would be helpful if you could make up your mind whether the issue was (1) advertising one's own work, or (2) not mentioning one's own work. Otherwise enjoy eating your cake and having it, too.

Comment: @MikhailKatz In case I haven't been clear enough: You asked about a question you have answered a few days before in a preprint *without mentioning the latter fact in your post until prompted to do so*. And there is a difference between mentioning ones work and using a question (!) to advertise one's own work.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, in case I haven't been clear enough: there is no merit to this verbiage concerning Cauchy.  I raised a broad issue of Cauchy interpretation at MO.  Whether or not I posted a reprint on the subject is immaterial since the issue is relevant whether or not I did.  Try to consider the possibility that folks are opposed to my Cauchy and other posts because it touches their belief systems on this topic and others.

Comment: Dima, there is a difference between talking about your work, and asking elaborate questions mainly for the sake of making your work visible.

Comment: Asaf, are you talking about the question we discussing, or about general character traits of its poster? 

I don't like how this thread has deteriorated into concluding that as MK has posted it, it must be such and such thing, and as someone is in general annoyed with MK, he'll vote to close this question too, without reading, simply by association.

Comment: @Dima: I am saying that after a person exhibits a certain type of behavior, his future actions are usually called into action (e.g. consistently put a bounty to prevent closure? All future bounties will be seen in that light). If a user shows a pattern of soapboxing, it is impossible to separate their questions from past actions. Yes, that is unfortunate, but this is reality. It works in the other direction, and we give more leeway to established users when it comes to borderline questions. Also, unlike you, I don't get notified of any comment here. So using `@Asaf` is necessary.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, Bringing up the Cauchy question seem to me a bad idea, and I see no justification for attacking the author of the question. ( Asaf )

Comment: @Gil: I can certainly see why you'd say that. But I can also certainly see why Michael, as a moderator on MSE, or why I, would claim that the author of that question is not using these platforms under what I'd say is "fair use". I agree that we need to be pluralistic, and accept more than we reject. But when people abuse the system, they also need to be held for a higher standard. I don't know about *this* question in play. I agree with Neil, which is why (in conjunction of the above) I had cast my vote to close. It is easy to see just one side, when you hear it in person from *that* side.

Comment: @Asaf there is no justification and no need for attacking the author (especially not by officers of these sites), and bringing up another question that we amply discussed is not useful.

Comment: @Gil: I think that I have my fair share of experience with people that when you isolate just one thing they do, it seems fine, but in the overall picture you see the emergent properties of "totally not fine". So I refuse *not* to judge a question by its author. As I pointed out before, we *all* do that, but we mostly do it in the sense of giving more leeway to established users, even you get that preferential treatment often, and I suspect many of your open and big lists would be closed, coming form an unregistered account. And it's fine, you've earned that. But for me? Katz earned *that*.

Comment: @Asaf, there is nor reason or justification to attack anybody in this discussion. 

(I did not remark on the issue of judging a question by its author, that like the issues of  "judging a question by its upvotes," or "judging a question by the quality of answers", we often discussed on Meta.) 

I also do not see how bringing the Cauchy question helps here. For example, I voted to open the Cauchy question (The question remained open, had positive net upvotes, and led to a couple of good answers).  Here, in view of Niel's answer, I am leaning in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Gil: I never brought up the Cauchy question. So I don't know what to tell you. I only brought up the fact that context derived from the author is relevant to the validity of a question. This is a site for mathematicians who honestly seek the help and companion of others. It is *not* a site for people who try and make their research look important. And that's all I have to say about that.

Comment: Dear Asaf, maybe we can agree about trying not to attack individuals and especially avoiding such attacks when they have small relevance to the discussed issue.

Comment: @GilKalai On some level I agree with you, who posted the question should not matter here. I would have voted to close if someone else has made it. But there is a general standard on MO, which I like, that people can sometimes post things that are slightly outside the rules when the contribution is useful and made in good faith. Since the question is not closed, I gave evidence why I don't think it was made in good faith. I think I did that in an appropriate manner; it's not like I called someone a hooligan.

Comment: It is a bit unclear whether this is supposed to be about this specific question or about close/reopen wars in general. (I am not sure whether that matters that much - since by now answers to *both* have been posted. But probably it's not good to mix two separate topic.) I will just remind that you can use the ([meta-tag:specific-question]) tag if you want to signal that you mainly ask about *this particular question* (rather than about a general issue) - see also [the tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/specific-question/info).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At various times in the past 9 years or so, we have tried several different social conventions to resolve the dissatisfaction that arises with the existing opening and closing rules.  This may not be a comprehensive list:

1. Person X with at least 3000 points would comment, "I vote to keep open", so that Person Y with at least 3000 points who wanted to close would have to comment, "I cancel X's vote" instead of actually voting to close.  I think this failed because most people didn't bother to follow this convention, and other people got upset by this, etc.
2. After n reopens, the question stays open, presumably enforced by moderator fiat.  I forgot how much n was, and I don't think we ever had a true consensus.  On the few occasions we did try that, people definitely got upset.

One benefit of the open/close system as it currently stands is that no one with qualifying score gets denied the opportunity to make a vote at some relevant time.  This sort of denial-of-voice seems to be the source of most people's frustration.  The other main source of frustration seems to be people who have an answer they want to write, but can't submit to a closed question.  However, there is a [specific place](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/223/requests-for-reopen-and-undelete-votes-for-on-hold-closed-and-deleted-question) where people can make reopen requests, and using it is much better than making lots of annoying minor edits to bump closed questions to the top in hopes of attracting 5 reopen votes.

For the most part, the questions where we encounter these problems are not precise research-level mathematics questions, which form the core of MathOverflow's mission.  While I appreciate the temporal and emotional investment in crafting a question, or writing an answer to a question, I do not think questions on the frontier of appropriateness on MathOverflow need special rules.

Comment: Overall, the present system is reasonable. I personally support an inclusive policy but there were other people who have different views. For this particular question, I found Neil's position convincing. 

One thing that I regard bad for MO and  I think moderators should, in general, not allow, is that when a problem was closed after a close/repopen war, the winning side will go on to delete the question altogether.

Comment: @GilKalai: I haven't been involved with this so far, but I think here deletion was the way to go. -- I think the valuable questions for MO are those which are (largely) uncontroversial. Keeping questions up which stir a lot of controversy causes a lot of noise without much benefit for anyone.

Answer (score 26):

I am profoundly opposed to the "cargo cult" question.  The internet is full of places where one can indulge in the pleasures of righteous indignation by mocking the failings of others.  I absolutely do not want Mathoverflow to join that sorry list.  People who agree with me have every right to vote for re-closure, as many times as necessary, and I hope that they will defend the culture of the site by exercising that right.

Comment: I would upvote this 100 times if I could.

Comment: then MO should forbid history of maths questions, in fact I would be happy if there was a separate venue on SE for this topic.

Comment: There is a history of science and mathematics forum.  Unfortunately, (if we are to take the post at face value), the question of Mikhail Katz does not belong there either.  Gerhard "May Look Into Reclose Option" Paseman, 2018.06.26.

Comment: Hmm, where would a history of maths question on, say, opposition to complex numbers belong to?

Comment: Usually, I dont like open/close wars and I usually suggest that people will be tolerant to questions thay do not like and on several occasions I voted to open questions that I did not upvote but felt that they need to stay open. In this particular case, Neil raised a valid concern: that the answers may mainly shame and mock some individuals. (I had some similar concerns about the notion of "Cargo Cult" but Mikhail explained  me that this is a widely used and accepted notion.) I think that Neil point is valuable. @MikhailKatz what is your response?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik In my view History of math questions are very valuable for MO. I dont see how you infer from Neil's answer anything against history of math questions.

Comment: @GilKalai - history of mathematics is impossible to separate from ethics and politics of and in mathematics. I read Neil's reply as he is opposed to the latter topics on MO. Perhaps he merely is unhappy about the world choice. Or perhaps he belongs to the school that teaches that mentioning errors explicitly is bad...

Comment: Dima, it is not impossible to seperate and in any case Niel's concern is that here "shaming" and "mocking" are central. (This is not just matter of word choice.) Indeed  mentioning and understanding errors is  important both in mathematics itself and in history of mathematics.

Comment: @GilKalai I went and edited out the most judgemental part of the question. I am still at loss trying to understand how to weed out ethics and politics in the history of maths, for it cannot be disconnected from persons being the results, conjectures, and errors. And these persons were affected by e.g. hiring and funding politics a lot.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Even though this is not explicit in the current answer, I'm pretty sure there is a major difference between writing negative things about Pythagoras and people who are still alive.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker - one may say that writing negative things about people who are no longer alive is not good, as they cannot respond to you in any way.
So this is all very much a question of taste and cultural upbringing. E.g. someone who grew up under an oppressive, intolerant to critics, regime would either never criticise anyone openly, or to the contrary, take pride in criticising anyone whom they see as deserving critique. 
I still remember the chair (Dutch, if it matters) of a conference session attempting to cut me short as I pointed out a methodological gap in a presentation.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker - and he commented to me later on that "this is not to be said" or something along these lines. 

So the next step would be to start to put on hold posts pointing at errors in papers of living mathematicians, just cause they would be upset?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I don't think one gets into trouble here for pointing out that someone made a methodological gap. That is far away from "cargo cult science". Of course, this doesn't differentiate between current math research and history. Or do you think nowadays math is about timeless truth, but fifty years ago math was mostly about politics and power?

Comment: Pointing out mistakes is not the same thing as "mocking the failings of others".@DimaPasechnik

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker there is a difference between honest mistakes and deliberate riding on a mistake. As we know that from a falsehood one can derive anything, so it suffices to insert one wrong lemma somewhere and go on building a beautiful (or not so beautiful) career.

E.g. there was a Clay scholar who was forced to retract all the publications that got him that post, and to leave maths. This half-killed the area he was active in, too. Are we supposed to be quiet about it, as to not hurt his feelings?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik If someone has a question related to that work, it is of course appropriate to point out that the work is flawed. But MO is not retraction watch, it is a Q&A site for research math.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker - I certainly think that maths is getting more and more about grant money, fashion ("everyone is doing X nowadays, we should also do X, or die" attitude),  politics and power, than science :-(

Comment: @Dima: And do you think it's okay for a user to use MO to make their research more visible, and as a leverage point of "oh, look, so many people think what I do is important, so give me money"? If cults are okay, we should also start a list of scammers and abusers. Don't you think?

Comment: @AsafKaragila - lists are fine, sure. If you ask me, high MO rating should count for something in your CV, yes. Do you mean to say you'd like to moderate honest QA for own research vs self-promotion? This sounds like very a hard task; a good question on your research or a good answer using your own research are self-promoting activities, for they increase rating, isn't it?


On the other hand I know about people getting grants to study MO! This is something I find a bit unethical...

Comment: @Dima: If I were to ask questions for the sole purpose of my papers ending up in the answers, written by my coauthors, and if I were to edit and bump these posts regularly, so I can claim that my research is always on the front page of MO, then I would be using this website in a very insincere way. Wouldn't I? Again, you think in a very naive way, about mentioning your research in an answer, or writing a follow up question related to your work. That much is fine. Working very hard to make sure that your research is visible to people on the front page, however... Not as fine.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. But careerism sustained by serial peer review failure is even less okay. Contact me privately if curious.

Answer (score 8):

One can always flag a question for moderator attention, use the flag to point out to the moderators that an open/close war is in progress, and ask for moderator intervention. In my (limited) experience, moderators will wait a while to see whether things settle down of their own accord, but will take some action if it gets to the point where they reckon enough's enough.

"Should there be a limit to the number of such rounds?" I reckon it's better to leave it up to the discretion of the moderators, than to specify a one-size-fits-all limit.

Answer (score 7):

For the reasons that others have described, I think that the existence of this question is damaging to MO.  There have already been nasty speculations in the comments threads about the characters of various people.  I have thus not only (previously) voted to close it, but I have also voted to delete the question.  I urge others to do likewise.

Comment: The question before us is, "Should there be a limit to the number of such rounds?" This is not an answer to that question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: True, but most of the other answers also solely address the merits of this specific question, so this seems to me like the logical place to put this answer.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: unlike on the main site, I have always thought that the purpose of meta is often to discuss, rather than just answer a question.

Comment: @Carl, sure, but to discuss what? To discuss whether there should be a limit to the number of open/close rounds? Sure. To discuss whether one specific question should be open/closed/deleted? That's a different issue, which could be discussed in response to a different question.

Comment: Would it be possible to split the question into two? Cause different answers answer different parts of the question. Dima "I just cannot stay on topic" Pasechnik.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I think you are being too rigid and literal with the rules.  I agree that on the main site answers should generally strictly address the question at hand (though there are times when I infer from context other questions that the asker really wants to know and answer them); however, on meta the tradition is that discussions are more freewheeling.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: See my previous comment to Gerry.

Comment: I'm amused that the comment I made here is meeting a very different reception than the exact same comment I made on Dima's answer, even though (to my way of thinking) the two comments were equally justified/unjustified.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think it makes sense to have higher demands for the one asking the question to stick to the actual question- given they could have asked whatever they wanted.

Comment: In my view, deleting the question is unreasonable.

Comment: @GilKalai Unfortunately my attention during the past few days was deflected by matters lying outside MO, but now having reviewed the matter some more, I find the question deeply problematic and do not find community-moderated deletion unreasonable. If I were to put the question in stark terms, it might be: what are some examples of outright incompetency or charlatanism that somehow passed through the filter of peer review? (It didn't appear to me that the author wanted examples of ordinary mistakes a mathematician might make.) It should be obvious why such a question is problematic.

Comment: Dear Todd, I agree that the question is problematic (But leaving it closed and undeleted would be fine in my view.). Judging from the asnwers and the examples given in the question, I dont think it is about  incompetency or charlatanism that somehow passed through the filter of peer review, but about examples of mathematically-based pseudoscience that had gained substantial attention, influence or support. I think it is useful to point out to people who voted to reopen that the question was not only closed but deleted, and to moderators...

Comment: (continued) and to propose to moderators that, *in the future*, will usually not allow a close/reopening dispute to end with a deletion of the question.

Comment: @GilKalai Thanks for clarifying your concern. Regarding your proposal: deletion and undeletion can see-saw just like opening and closing, and as Scott Carnahan said, site moderator intervention in that process would be seen as denial-of-voice, and I am leery of setting up a general rule like you suggest for that reason. Finally (for what interest it may have), here is an extract from Wikipedia on the use of the word 'charlatan': "Rather, the person called a charlatan is being accused of resorting to quackery, pseudoscience, or some knowingly employed bogus means of impressing people...".

Comment: @GilKalai: While I agree that in normal circumstances there is no need to delete closed questions, this is an exceptional case.  Let me spell out my concerns more explicitly.  One of my colleagues shares an unusual last name with a notorious crank (but is not related to him).  Someone brought this up in the comments.  Since people were actively paying attention, this was eventually deleted.  But if the question is closed but not deleted, then inevitably in the future someone will leave a similarly slanderous comment, and no one will be paying attention enough to notice. (continued)

Comment: This kind of thing can be extremely damaging to someone’s career — MO questions are highly ranked on google, so the question will show up when someone’s name is googled.  Given this danger, I cannot see any alternative to deleting this question.  Slander, mean-spirited rumors and gossip, etc are completely inappropriate for MO.

Comment: Andy, thanks, I appreciate your point of view.

Comment: (ps: on re-reading my comment, it might appear that my concern is narrowly one about my colleague.  But it is a far more general concern; who knows what drive-by comments will be made in the future...).

Comment: @AndyPutman Agreed. As I commented below, this type of thing does indeed potentially open up liabilities, and this is yet another insidious effect of sustained charlatanism. While I entirely agree that MO is not the place to call out such behavior, my own experience leads me to wonder if there is any socially allowed forum, or if we are meant to tolerate (or even indulge) a certain amount of system-gaming for some higher purpose.

Comment: https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A06856857 they think it is a valuable MO question...

Comment: Drive-by comments can be done to any question, not just to this one. I have never made any judgemental comments about any active mathematician, anyway.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Yes, but this particular question is **asking** for inappropriate comments.  As far as the link on zentrallblat, my guess is that it is an automatic trackback to MO questions that link to the particular review.  Saying that it is a judgement by the editors of ZB that this is a valuable question is grasping at straws to justify a blatantly inappropriate post.

Comment: @Dima: I'm confused by the zbmath link. I don't see any mention of MathOverflow, or any indication that the people who wrote that statement meant it as a statement about MathOverflow.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - I do see it right above Keywords.

Comment: @Dima: Ah. My bad. I suspect that this is an automated addition, once the review was linked in the main question.

Comment: @Dima: Yeah, for example https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0589.03033 was definitely written long before MathOverflow existed.

Answer (score -6):

To me, the value of the question we talk about is that it is (well, formulated perhaps in too strong words, and all that) very much relevant to well-being of mathematics as a science.

Cargo cults (deliberate attempts to create a pseudo-area and build up a career on it) are quite damaging: they suck up funding, they kill/damage adjacent honest research areas, they damage community morale.

Having a list of such cults available on MO looks useful to me.

Comment: The question before us is, "Should there be a limit to the number of such rounds?" This is not an answer to that question.

Comment: I agree - it was poorly formulated in the beginning. Mea culpa.

Comment: So in other words, under this reading, the question becomes: what are some examples of *charlatanism* that somehow passed the filter of peer review? This type of question is *really problematic*. In comments at the main site you had referred to the case of a mathematician-turned-politician where you offered an *opinion* that in some of his work he was not being intellectually honest -- quite a serious charge, and really not fit for MO. I'm not a lawyer, but this type of thing potentially opens up legal liabilities.

Comment: @ToddTrimble This type of thing does indeed potentially open up liabilities, and this is yet another insidious effect of sustained charlatanism. While I entirely agree that MO is not the place to call out such behavior, my own experience leads me to wonder if there is any socially allowed forum, or if we are meant to tolerate (or even indulge) a certain amount of system-gaming for some higher purpose.

Comment: @AdamEpstein I'm afraid I have no good answer to that question, alas.